# How to stop Windows service C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

My windows service is creating 1 thread in OnStart() method. The code of thread contains 1 while loop and looks like this:

```
    Thread mworker;       
    AutoResetEvent mStop = new AutoResetEvent(false); 
     protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    // TODO: Add code here to start your service.

    mworker = new Thread(pwd_fetch);
    mworker.IsBackground = false;
    mworker.Start();
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    // TODO: Add code here to perform any tear-down necessary to stop your service.
    mStop.Set();
    mworker.Join();
}

private void pwd_fetch()
{
    while(true)
    {
        //some other code

        if (mStop.Set()==true)
            break;
    }
}
```

I want while loop condition as true, but to break the loop I'm using if() instruction, but still unable to stop service.

Anybody know, why this is so? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: what is mStop and Set is property or method. If it's method then Set is returning false in every condition.

Comment: refer to know about Set and WaitOne with AutoresetEvent http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx

Answer (score 2):

To stop the service you have to call the servicecontroller instance and stop it

```
ServiceController service = new ServiceController("ServiceName");
service .Stop();
```

Answer (score 2):

In your thread loop method, you need to use the mStop.WaitOne (with a timeout).  Calling set will set the handle... that's not what you want to do here.

```
 if (mStop.WaitOne(500))
     break;
```

Comment: I'd suggest attaching the visual studio debugger to your running service.  Set breakpoints in the OnStop() and pwd_fetch() routines to see what's going on.  Try to stop the service and see what breakpoints are hit and what is happening.  This should do the trick.

Comment: after mStop.Set() instruction breakpoint comes to mworker.join(). breakpoint never goes into pwd_fetch()

Comment: Just a guess: Perhaps something else is resetting your mStop?  It is an AutoResetEvent.. any Wait (or Reset) would do it and prevent your loop from exiting.  In this case, a manual reset event might be a safer bet.  Other than that, I can only suggest to keep stepping through your thread loop with the debugger and see what's being hit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the service to stop itself, you can simply call:

```
this.Stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your thread code in the service started event, and not on starting.

Answer (score 0):

1.Use a boolean variable instead of "true" always in while loop
Then you can set it to false where you need to terminate the codes inside the loop.

2.Call mworker.Abort() to stop the thread.

3.Stop service by

`new ServiceController("ServiceName").Stop();`